# Jquery accordion content height doesn't auto fit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, accordion

I populate my accordion dynamically through API query, for some reason it doesn't auto-size itself based on my content height. I've already set `height style: "content",` and it still doesn't work. How can I set the height to auto-fit my content and remove the overflow?

[image]

Here's my code :
HTML :

```
<div id="job_accordion" class=""></div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("https://api/open/jobs/?page_size=1000")
        .done(function (data) {
            let jobs_list = data.results.sort((a, b) => (a.organization_name > b.organization_name) ? 1 : -1)
            let department_name = "";
            $.each(jobs_list, function (index, job) {
                let department_id = job.organization_name.toLowerCase();
                if (department_name != job.organization_name) {
                    $('#job_accordion').append(`
                                                <!--${job.organization_name}-->
                                                <button class="accordion">${job.organization_name}</button>
                                                <div class="panel">
                                                    <ol id="${department_id}_list">
                                                    </ol>
                                                </div>`
                    );
                    department_name = job.organization_name;
                }
                $(`#${department_id}_list`).append(`<li>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-job" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#job_modal" onClick="displayJobModal(${job.id})">
                                                        ${job.position_name}
                                                        </button>
                                                    </li>`);
            });

            $("#job_accordion").accordion({
                event: 'click',
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                // autoHeight: false,
                fillSpace: true,
                clearStyle: true,
                heightStyle: "content",
                animate: 200,
                icons: false
            }).children('li').on('mouseenter', function () {
                $(this).find('h3').trigger('click');
            });

        })
        .fail(function (request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .always(function () {
        });

});
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        #job_accordion .ui-accordion-header a {
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 42px;
            display: block;
            font-size: 12pt;
            width: 100%;
            text-indent: 10px;
        }

        #job_accordion .panel {
            border: 0;
            color: #fff;
            background: #000;
            /*padding: 0 0 5em 0; */
            border-top: 0;
            /*overflow: hidden;*/
            /*height: 1000px;*/
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, set max-height to fit-content.

```
#job_accordion .panel {
            border: 0;
            color: #fff;
            background: #000;
            padding: 0 0 0 0;
            border-top: 0;
            max-height: fit-content;
        }
```